# Format float with the same number of significant decimals

Tags: c#, floating-point, number-formatting, decimal

What i would like to do is to format number with the same amount of significant decimals.

Example:

```
var a1 = 0.123456789;
var b1 = 0.00123456789;
var c1 = 123.456789;
var a2 = string.Format("????", a1); // the result i want is "0.123"
var b2 = string.Format("????", b1); // the result i want is "0.00123"
var c2 = string.Format("????", c1); // the result i want is "123.456"
```

I want to use this for presentation formatting of exchange rates.

BR
Andreas

Comment: I use C# so example in that language is preferred :o)

Answer (score 2):

```
var a1 = 0.123456789;
var b1 = 0.00123456789;
var a2 = string.Format("{0:G3}", a1);
var b2 = string.Format("{0:G3}", b1);
```

Edit:

```
var a = 123.456789;
var n = string.Format("{0:F0}", a);
var d = string.Format("{0:G3}", a - (int)a);
if (d.Length > 2)
    n = n + d.Substring(1);

label1.Text = n;
```

Comment: Funny, I just compiled one of my first C# programs to test if this would work (which it does).

Comment: Sorry for being a bit unclear, Included one more case 123.456... If i use this formatting i just get 123. The 3 decimals will not be included.

Comment: So you want a precision of 3, but only behind the comma?

Comment: That may work with a little cutting up strings. See my edit. (C# seems to be fun :))

Comment: But know that you are actually adding significant digits. Some math people may not like this.